# How to stress the word "resource" in noun and verb form

Tags: pronunciation

In my impression, a word with both noun and verb forms should be stressed on the first syllable when it is a noun, and on the second or subsequent syllable when it is a verb.

A search in Cambridge Dictionary finds that the word "resource" seems to be unbound by this rule of thumb. 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resource

Is it correct if I continue to pronounce "REsource" in noun form and "reSORce" in verb form?

Comment: Can you give an example of a word that you think *is* bound by this rule?

Comment: Hello #Andrew .  A common example is the word "conduct", which is also mentioned in this following website I found over the Internet. The website gives a pretty clear list of examples bound by this rule of thumb. Here is the link =>>  https://goo.gl/3tszwB

Comment: Personally, I don't see the need for it, but hey, you could always do whatever you want and let your listener figure it out for herself :D.

Comment: The "rule" only applies on some occasions. Your best bet is to check the dictionary for pronunciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Conduct" is a good example, although again given that it's difficult to think of other examples I expect it's more an occasional pattern rather than any kind of actual "rule".  As a counter-example consider *alert*, always pronounced "a-LERT" regardless of whether it's a noun, an adjective, or a verb.

As you say, it's "RE-source" when used as a noun and (often, not always) "re-SOURCE" when used as a verb, and similarly with "contest" or "decrease" (and many others), but I think for every few that match this pattern you'll find at least one that doesn't ([*address, bandage, challenge,* etc.](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/nounandverb.shtml))

Comment: Correction:  People pronounce the noun "address" both as "ADress" and "aDress".  I guess if you're looking for consistency in English you've come to the wrong language  :)

Answer (score 2):

The rule [you cite](http://www.businessenglishresources.com/31-2/teachers-section/mini-lessons/pronunciation-lessons-pronunciation-changes-in-words-that-are-both-nouns-and-verbs/) is correct for the list of verbs given at that resource. But the rule does not apply to all verbs. For example, the word *action* is nowadays used as a verb in business English (perhaps more so in British English) but it is pronounced the same as the noun *action*. The list of verbs following the "rule" is a good one to know, but for other verbs  the best thing you can do is look them  up in the dictionary, as you have done for *resource*.